# Controller does not catch CSS

Tags: css, spring

I'm trying to connect CSS to my html pages over the Spring.

[resource tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg8an.png)

It works (I see content with different colors) when I launch it by hands with direct path:
file:///C:/Users/Rom/src/main/resources/templates/people/index.html

But it does not work, when I launch it with Controller over http://localhost:8080/people
I'm receiving the page, but without colors.

The index.html:

```
<html lang="en">
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>All people</title>
    <link href="../../static/css/StyleCSS.css" th:href="@{/css/StyleCSS.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>
```

**What's wrong?**

I've tried different variants:

th:href="@{../../css/StyleCSS.css}"

th:href="@{/resources/css/StyleCSS.css}"

tried to remove from the string href="../../static/css/StyleCSS.css"

Comment: And you haven't tried `/static/css/StyleCSS.css`....

Comment: No, I've tried this one. It does not help.

Comment: I assume you are using Spring boot, using a `href="/static/css/StyleCSS.css` with that should work (if you haven't disable auto config). Your file should be under `src/main/resources/static/css` so not in the templates folder.

Comment: Yep, i'm using Spring bot. And the tree is as you've said (check picture in the post). But it steel does not work. I've tried 
<link href="/static/css/StyleCSS.css" th:href="@{/static/css/StyleCSS.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
and
<link href="/static/css/StyleCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

Comment: Which means you probably disabled auto configuration... What does your configuration look like.

Comment: Do you mean annotation for Controller? Like this:
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/people")
public class MainControllers {

Comment: No your configuration.... The `@Configuration` classes you have. And please don't add those as comments as that is totally unreadable.

Comment: uploaded it here https://github.com/Kozlachkov/blog/blob/master/src/main/java/com/kozlachkov/config/SpringConfig.java

Comment: And there is your problem... Ditch that configuration as you are using Spring Boot. Move the datasource information to the `application.properties`... Restart app and you are done. You are trying to work around the sprig boot auto configuration.

Comment: Probably I understood smth wrong. Could you check the link once again (I've updated it). Moved DB data to application. properties. The program works as before, but CSS still is not catched.

Comment: You shouldn't update it you should remove that class in its totality

Comment: Could you give some more details? What is exact problem in this class? Do I correctly understand, that if I remove Bean datasSource and Bean jdbcTemplate from there , the program will accept CSS ?

Comment: Those beans aren't the problem (although also disable auto config to some extend). What you are doing in your configuration class isn't needed as that is all done by Spring Boot. The `@EnableWebMvc` disables the web auto configuration for Spring MVC including the mapping for loading static files. So basically all this configuration does is work against Spring Boot instead of with it.

Comment: So, you mean I need remove from SpringConfig annotation @EnableWebMvc, remove  implementation of WebMvcConfigurer from the class and remove dependency "spring-webmvc" ? Then it should work?

Comment: No... You should remove the configuration class. The whole class.... Where did you pickup that you  need to remove the dependency? I only ever mentioned that configuration class.

Comment: OK, but how can I do my Configuration than? Where do I store my beans?

Comment: again you don't need those, as mentioned before Spring Boot **already creates those**...

Comment: Wow. Thank you. Feels like there are some blank spots in my knowledge. Can you recommend smth to read or watch on this subject? For now I've moved all beans to Application, removed SpringConfig and the program works + catched CSS. Now I will try to remove all beans one by one too see how the program change it's behavior, may be it will help for better understanding. And thank you a lot for your huge-huge patience!!!

Comment: Questions on links to resources are considered offtopic. But the guides on spring.io are a good start, or buy my one of my books on Spring Boot and Spring ;).

Comment: Could you give a link on your books?

Comment: Links to my website are in my profile, which contains links to books (and a blog which I occasionally use to blog).

Comment: your profile shows this site "http://mdeinum.wordpress.com" which looks like deleted :) Can I ask you one more question similar to previous one? I'm trying to insert image by <img src="../../images/heading.jpg" th:src="@{images/heading.jpg}" width="624px"  height="40" /> And the result is similar to what was with CSS. I can see it over manual tracking in browser and it does not shown over Spring.  Updated github https://github.com/Kozlachkov/blog/blob/master/src/main/resources/templates/people/index.html

Comment: Hmm. Thats weird, I explicitly added https://deinum.biz... So that must be something old... Please don't ask additional questions in comments, but rather a new question. One thing use absolute paths instead of relative ones and the images should e in /static as well.

Comment: I don't see that site in my profile... Wonder where you see it? Hmm apparently there are 2 profiles (doh)...